# Apache2 vhost *:80 vs ip:80

Tags: apache-2.2, apache-2.4, virtualhost

I have pretty simple question, but still I have not found clear explanation of that.
What is the practical difference between *:80 and some_ip:80 in virtual host conf?
Is it like *:80 listens on all interfaces and some_ip only on that interface where this some_ip is configured? So practically if i have only one vhost on server there is no much difference?

Comment: Yes indeed. The idea is that you can have among others a different default virtualhost for each ip-address, which was useful for instance with SSL in the times before SNI became prevalent and on multi-homed servers. With only a single ip-address there is little benefit to restricting the virtualhost to a specific ip-address.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is the practical difference between *:80 and some_ip:80 in virtual host conf? Is it like *:80 listens on all interfaces and some_ip only on that interface where this some_ip is configured?

YES

> So practically if i have only one vhost on server there is no much difference?

Not exactly. If you have multiple IP addresses, and you want to restrict the HTTP traffic to a given address, then you want to bind your vhost to that address, not `*`. Even with 1 VHOST you may want to do that.

Comment: I happened upon this question as I was debugging an issue and wanted to point out, it appears that virtual hosts set up with the more specific `some_ip:80` get a higher priority in routing than those with a general `*:80`. I had a site set up with `*:80` and when I added a virtual host with `some_ip:80` (not sure why I did that), traffic to the first site was redirected to the second. It wasn't until I set both up as `*:80` (or both as `some_ip:80`) that both sites routed correctly.